Нужно ли обособлять имя?
«Около месяца тому назад третий сын лорда Лотрюда (—/,) Эверард (—/,) связал себя узами брака с графиней Турпинена (—/,) Одерикой».
Нужно ли ставить тире или запятую? Или вовсе ничего не ставить?

В качестве варианта:
Около месяца тому назад третий сын лорда Лотрюда Эверард  связал себя узами брака с графиней Турпинена, Одерикой.
Пояснение
Что надо знать по теме?  Решение во многом грамматическое — это правописание сочетаний вида НАР + СОБСТВ (нарицательное сущ. + имя собственное). При таком порядке слов возможна как определительная конструкция без знака (приложение + определение), так и уточняющая (обособление запятой).
Выбор делается по контексту. Можно, к примеру, предположить, что у лорда был единственный сын Эверард (нет уточнения), и он вступил в брак с графиней Турпинена. А имя графини не так важно и приводится как уточнение.
Тире в подобных случаях (для нераспространенных имен) практически не используется. Отметим также, что решение делается  для конкретного предложения с учетом обстоятельств, известных по тексту. Это тот основной ФАКТОР, который следует учитывать.
Примечание (о произношении)
В устной речи присутствуют паузы грамматические и произносительные. Грамматические паузы выделенные, подчеркнутые, на письме они обозначаются запятыми. Назначение произносительных пауз ясно из их названия — мы не можем произносить длинные фразы на одном дыхании и поэтому делим на речевые отрезки даже простое предложение, в котором нет запятых. Итак, произносительные паузы знаками не обозначаются.
ПРИМЕР деления предложения паузами на речевые отрезки:
Около месяца тому назад / третий сын лорда Лотрюда Эверард / связал себя узами брака с графиней Турпинена, // Одерикой.

• В правилах Розенталя о такой ситуации говорится:

6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его): <...> А братья Ани, Петя и Андрюша, гимназисты, дёргали отца сзади за фрак (Ч.); Четвёртый сын ещё совсем мальчик, Вася (Пауст.); У дверей, на солнышке, зажмурившись, лежала любимая борзая собака отца, Милка (Л. Т.)...
Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении. Ср.:
...Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу; Он сына моего, Борьку, напомнил...
Вошла её сестра Мария; Сегодня я и друг мой Серёжа уезжаем на юг; Выступал староста группы Коля Петров; По дороге нам встретился главный инженер Жуков.

• Итак, выбор за автором.
Я бы написала так:
Около месяца тому назад третий сын лорда Лотрюда, Эверард, связал себя узами брака с графиней Турпинена Одерикой».
• Объяснения
Читать и произносить "третий сын лорда Лотрюда Эверард" без передыху трудно, приходится делать паузу. Обозначим ее запятыми.
Если графиня в Турпинене только собственно Одерика, то запятую, считаю, можно не ставить. Если же графинь несколько и надо назвать (выбрать) только одну, то запятую ставим.
Приложения одиночные, поэтому мне кажется, что достаточно запятой.
• Примеры из Нацкорпуса
А третий сын Марьям, Ямиль, меньшой, с ленивыми мозгами...
Третий сын шаха, Аббас-Мирза, овладевший Адербиджаном...
У них в то время только что родился их третий сын, Петр...
Недавно третий сын кайзера, принц Альберт, отправился в Австрию...
Третий сын Варвары Алексеевны, Арсений Абрамович, тоже женился в молодых годах...
На этот раз, по примеру отца, им оказался третий сын Александра II — Его Императорское Высочество великий князь Владимир Александрович (А. Г. Колмогоров. Мне доставшееся: Семейные хроники Надежды Лухмановой).
[Распространенное приложение стоит в конце предложения, поэтому обособляется с помощью тире.]
Обособленные приложения
